# Docker Swarm on Ceph

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, ceph

Good day.

I am looking for some persistent storage for docker swarm nodes. Ceph looks good, but how to connect nodes? In case of RBD we will need some cluster FS. 
What about CephFS, will it be good with docker swarm?

Comment: Take a look at flocker which supports ceph.

Answer (score 2):

can you look at glusterfs as a storage solution for docker swarm.
The below link would be helpful

http://embaby.com/blog/using-glusterfs-docker-swarm-cluster/

Answer (score 2):

I have used Ceph and Rexray with some success for docker swarm persistence. The only issue I had is that a volume can only be mounted by one container at a time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846675/758542